# Creating a Tuple<List<Model>, Model> to pass as a model to Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a beginner at using MVC3 with the razor syntax. I want to know how can I write for `@html.partial`.

In ProductVarient.cshtml, I will call the partial view as follows:

```
 @{
     var dataDictAttributes = new ViewDataDictionary();
     dataDictAttributes.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("attributes_{0}", Model.Id);
     @Html.Partial("_ProductAttributes", Tuple.Create<List<Model.ProductVariantAttributes>, Model>(dataDictAttributes,model));                  
 }
```

I want to know the syntax for passing the parameters to `@html.partial()`. Also, where it should be changed, in the controller or the model?

In _ProductAttributes.cshtml, I have declared the model as follows:

```
@model Tuple<IList<ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantAttributeModel>,ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantAttributeModel>
```

Error occurs as follows:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

In the model:

```
public class ProductVariantAttributeModel : BaseNopEntityModel
{
    public ProductVariantAttributeModel();

    public IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions { get; set; }
    public AttributeControlType AttributeControlType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Products.Qty")]
    public int EnteredQuantity { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductAttributeId { get; set; }
    public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedDay { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedMonth { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public string TextPrompt { get; set; }
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantAttributeValueModel> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you able to clarify what you are trying to do? Expand on your issue?

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: He's trying to pass a tupel into his partial view, however I don't think his understand of tuple is correct.

Comment: @mon Please post your model code so I can help you.

Comment: @mon, I took the liberty to rename your question to better reflect what you are trying to achieve. The `turple` you stated there was probably one of the reasons for downvotes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace your `Partial()` call with

```
 @Html.Partial("_ProductAttributes", Tuple.Create<IList<ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantAttributeModel>,ProductDetailsModel.ProductVariantModel.ProductVariantAttributeModel>(dataDictAttributes,model));
```